# Using solar sails to accelerate a planet’s rotation

Tags: planets, terraforming, day-night, solar-sails

So, just pondering on methods of terraforming venus, it seems that the first step regardless of what comes is to speed up its rotation. This will strengthen its magnetic field, not to mention cool off the surface somewhat, and then we can muck about with converting the atmosphere to water with hydrogen, importing life forms etc. ANYWAY…

There are various ideas of spinning this tip, all of which seem to involve Dyson swarms and masses of energy. However, I have come up with what is potentially a much more economic solution, which I would like your lot’s opinion on.

A series of huge solar sails is built; each one is 99% reflective on one side, and 99% light-absorbent on the other, and tethered to Venus’ surface by ultra-strong nanotube cables. Each sail is tethered at an angle in order to catch the sun’s rays, causing it to move and so pull at the planet. The effect of each sail would by tiny, but a swarm of then, tethered in a ring around venus’ equator, could gradually accelerate the planet’s rotation to 24 hours over time.

1 Would this system work?

2 if not, what are the flaws?

3 how long would this take?

Comment: You are grossly underestimating how big and heavy a planet is. Or maybe I am grossly underestimating how many billions of years you are prepared to wait. (And you may want to redo the calculation, because the way I see it the force will rather change the orbit of the planet instead of accelerating its rotation. Conservation of angular momentum is a bitch.)

Comment: Indeed @AlexP.  Even if you pull harder ! Say, ion motors.. impulse engines.. you can transport the energy needed for these engines via the tether and it will work continuously all around. Wait a few centuries.. and your planet will go 10 seconds per day faster (just an estimation, no hard science)

Comment: A faster "orbit" equals one of two things .. either you break orbit and fly away from your primary off into space never to be seen again (in your original galactic post code) .. or (to avoid that) you have to arrange to move closer to your primary as you increase the speed of your orbit .. but I suspect you may not have meant orbit but rather the spin or rotation on which it's day night cycle relies? .. your orbit of twenty four hours is really rather fast, consider that we take a year and Venus around two thirds of a year at present.

Comment: Two points - it is unclear if you are actually looking at Venus' orbit or the rate of its rotation about its own axis.  An "orbit" of 24 hours around Sol is much, much closer than the orbit of Mercury, and may be as unsustainable as a 60 minute orbit around Earth.  Second point is that if the solar sails are 99% light absorbent on one side then they are absorbing a lot of heat - without a mechanism to dump that heat then they will eventually melt, whatever they are made of, or the heat is transferred to Venus and makes it even hotter (= less habitable).

Comment: Yet again... **One and only one question** (VTC:Needs More Focus). And in addition to the other comments, If you don't pull the sail in for half the planet's rotation, you're going to have a net effect of zero. The energy to pull in and push out the sail IMO overwelms the value of the sail as a means of pushing the planet. And that's assuming you can build an infrastructure that could handle the stress.

Answer (score 1):

You have just rediscovered the [Yarkovsky effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarkovsky_effect)

> The Yarkovsky effect is a force acting on a rotating body in space caused by the anisotropic emission of thermal photons, which carry momentum. It is usually considered in relation to meteoroids or small asteroids (about 10 cm to 10 km in diameter), as its influence is most significant for these bodies.
>
> The Yarkovsky effect is a consequence of the fact that change in the temperature of an object warmed by radiation (and therefore the intensity of thermal radiation from the object) lags behind changes in the incoming radiation. That is, the surface of the object takes time to become warm when first illuminated, and takes time to cool down when illumination stops.
>
> In general, the effect is size-dependent, and will affect the semi-major axis of smaller asteroids, while leaving large asteroids practically unaffected. For kilometre-sized asteroids, the Yarkovsky effect is minuscule over short periods: the force on asteroid 6489 Golevka has been estimated at 0.25 newtons, for a net acceleration of $10^{−12} m/s^2$. But it is steady; over millions of years an asteroid's orbit can be perturbed enough to transport it from the asteroid belt to the inner Solar System.

As you can read above, the effect influences the orbit, not the rotation, and it is significant only for rather small bodies. Definitely not for planets.

Comment: If one attaches a sail to one side of a sphere, the sail force induces a torque which affects the angular momentum as well as linear momentum, no?

Comment: I think this system does not only rely on the Yarkovsky effect, but also on an effect of having those sails react on solar pressure and transfer physical momentum to the planet, which is expected to be MUCH bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Would this system work - **NO**, the reason is that your sails would fall to Venus. Even an ultra-strong tether has enough mass to collapse under its own weight, since we are using real world physics, it's the very reason (the biggest one, but other major obstacles are also present) that the space lift isn't yet built, and even no attempts have been made to build one. In order for this to work, you have to build a space lift that's tethered to the surface and is strong enough to absorb bending forces at level length of thousands of kilometers. And this is for Earth, where rotation is already present so that there's a geostationary orbit that allows creating a space tether (aka space lift) so that its mass center is up there and thus it does not fall down to Earth. For Venus, given its retrograde rotation speed at 5832 hours ([source](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/venusfact.html)) per revolution, its stationary orbit is too far from Venus' surface to allow any similar mechanism to rely on revolution as means to not fall down on Venus. And using solid towers can only bring you barely outside the cloud layer, meaning your sails are limited in size, However with towers up the atmosphere you might still achieve some effect, which can be calculated.

Let's assume you've got a complete equatorial ring of supporting megastructures built, with height over 40 kilometers above the surface (and these can well collapse under their own weight already), with 100 km wide and 1 km high "sails" installed and protected from atmospheric wearout, the sun-facing side is reflective on the retrograde side of planet (left, if looking from the Sun and having Venus revolve leftwards) and absorbing on the other side of the planet. The sides are chosen so that there is already a momentum effect in revolution of Venus relative to the Sun, which we seek to amplify. Now, given the irradiation of Venus at 2600 W/m^2, and reflective area of all the sails of 100km*half the Venus' disc, that would be 100*3000 = 3e5 km^2 = 3e11 m^2, and average angle of reflection being 45 degrees, your installation would reflect 7.8e14 J of light per second, producing an integral force of 7.8e14/3e8 = 2.6e6 N at length of 3100 km, along the surface, thus delivering 8e12 N*m of torque. The effects of winds against those sails are assumed zero since we are aiming to accelerate the entire planet, together with its atmosphere, so any interaction within the planet is providing zero momentum to the planet as a whole. The corresponding other side is assumed black, absorbing all 7.8e14 J of light together with its momentum, which would produce about half of 8e12 N*m of momentum, and the resultant effect would be equal to the remaining half, or 4e12 N*m.

Now, we're trying to spin Venus, it has a moment of inertia at 0.337Mr^2 which is 0.337*4.86e24*3051e3^2 = 0.337*4.524e37 kg*m^2 =1.525e37 kg*m^2 , thus our 4e12 Nm torque would apply angular acceleration of 3e-25 rad/s^2 to the planet. Since we need to reach 2*PI/86400 rad/s from existing "almost zero", it will take about 3.3e20 seconds or 1.06e13 years. Given that the Sun's estimated lifespan is in the ballpark of 4e9 years, you are short of time by a factor of 3000, and you need to invent a better project.

Comment: "Let's assume you've got a complete equatorial ring ... and these can well collapse under their own weight." The idea of orbital rings is that the inner ring (ex. a long copper wire) revolves at greater than orbital velocity resulting in an upward force that is used to support structures, like the rest of the ring. If this isn't enough, active support can alleviate compression members from the ground. The orbital ring is loaded largely in tension, not compression, and doesn't support itself like a building on Earth would, and so wouldn't collapse under its own weight.

Comment: @BMF I meant the ring consists of ground-based towers, each having a sail on top. Having a solid ring in orbit is quite different, and has troubles of transferring momentum to the planet. The initial project consisted of sails attached (tethered) to the ground, so I started off from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets give it a shot with some math.

You are right, spinning up Venus would be a vital step in any useful terraforming efford. However, it is not nearly as complicated as people think it is.

Venus, according to science, is heavy and big. Now, the question is how much energy we need to spin her up, to say a 24 hour cycle. Thankfully there is math of this, which if you do it, gives you the number;

$1.88525\times10^{29}$ Joule.

To you and me, this seems like a rather big number. Which is because it is. Any number that has e29 behind it can safly be considered big. However, its really not *that* much. Its the kind of Energy requierment you can reasonably deliver withouth straight up magic.

This Energy needs to be transfered into Angular Momentum for Venus to really do much with it. And this is the tricky part. You see, due to **the laws of the Universe** we are not allowed to have fun and as such every energy conversion process has inefficencies. And while for simple pesants like you and me, an efficency of say 80% might sound pretty good, if your goal is to induce e29 Joules into anything, 80% is a failure. What we need, is the most direct way to transform Electricty (which prosumably is the base energy we have) into Rotational or really Kinetic energy. Which, for all intend, is some sort of mass Driver system.

[image]

We can do this because the conservation of angular momentum dosnt magically stop working at a Planetary scale. Now, there are a few downsides to this approach.

- we need to get rid of the Atmosphere before otherwise its drag will make this plan impossible
- We need to fire these Mass Drivers in some fashion continously as to now allow internal friction to just absorb all the Energy. Right, Venus has a ***lot*** of Intertia. And we need to make sure that does not absorb energy continously.
- We need a lot of Mass Drivers
- We need a lot of Power
- We need at least like 300 Years

Now, this last part might be a supprise. But it turns out if you run the numbers and account for the loses duo to intertia, yeah you can spin venus up in 300 Years. That is provided you got 1400 Mass Drivers firing a 100 Ton Projectile at 1000km/s every 84 Minutes for 300 Years. Realistically, you need double the number of Mass Drivers because systems like this will fail and or need to be maintained. But, the math and physics check out.

With all of this in mind, why is using Solar Sails such a bad approach ? Well for a start, because its not a lot of Energy you can capture that way. The sun is powerful but taking loses into account you wont reflect 99% of light or absorb 99% of light. The Visible range is huge after all.

Another issue is our good old friend inertia again. If you mount a bunch of Solar Sails with long cables to Venus, those cables will lose 10% of their energy to vibrations and friction right off the bet. Now, there is a bit of an advantage to sails because their Radius to the planetary center is bigger. So you get more bang for your bug. But the truth of the matter is that a 100 Ton Projectile flying at 1000km/s carries more energy than a sail can capture in an hour.

Yet another issue are the orbits of the Sails. Since they are tugging on the planet they are not in orbit. So what is stopping them from falling down ?

And the list truly goes on.

If you want to Terraform venus, the basic steps are:

1. Build a big shade at the L1 point and block out all the light
2. Wait like a solid 150 Years for the Atmosphere to turn solid
3. Build a load of Mass Drivers on the frozen Surface and start blasting. In the meantime you need to shoot a few billion tons of Carbon Dioxide Ice into space as well. Which you can do via very big engines at the poles that literally just shoot the Co2 into space.
4. Do both of these for about 300 Years
5. Congrats, you have a Spinning Venus with no Atmosphere but a lot of frozen Nitrogen, Oxygen and a bit of Co2.
6. Open the Shade, a bit not fully
7. Give it like a solid 500-1000 Years for a full Ecology to evolve

Comment: Something isn't adding up. 1,400 drivers all launching 100 ton projectiles amounts to 140,000,000 kg every 84 minutes. There are about 18,800 84 minute intervals in the span of 300 years (~1,600,000/84), bringing the total ejected mass to 2.6E12 kg. Using Newtonian kinetic energy, I get a total of 1.3E24 Joules from that much matter flying at 1000 km/s, 5 orders of magnitude less than you need.

Comment: Lemme check, maybe i included a wrong number. 100 Ton Projectiles, 1000km/s euqlas 5e16 Joule. Which equals 3.7705e+12 firing sequences. Aha, there is the problem. My notes used about half that many sequences. But ok, with the new number we have 2693214285 Sequences per Mass Driver over 300 Years. So 17 Firings per Minute. Good spot ! Id argue it is still possible though a lot more expensive